# JavaScript in slider image

Tags: javascript

I have a slider on my e-commerce homepage but it is freeze .I need to change it after 3 second .... Thanks in advance.

```
function aweMainSlider() {
    var e = $(".main-slider");
    e.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        nav: !0,
        dots: !0,
        onInitialized: function() {
            e.find(".owl-item").each(function() {
                var e = $(this),
                o = e.find(".main-slider-item"),
                a = e.find(".main-slider-image > img");
                o.length && a.length && (o.addClass("background"),         
                o.css("background-image", "url(" + a.attr("src") + ")"), a.css({
                    opacity: 0,
                    visibility: "hidden"
                }))
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add a plunker?

Comment: I don't understand th part which started at `o.length && a.length ...`. I tried and there is a syntax error.